# Password hashing and adding zero

Tags: c#, sql, .net, api

i trying a user login/register template and
when i do register a user  i doing hashing like this

```
public class HashingHelper
    {
       public static void CreatePasswordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt) 
        {
            using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512())
            {
                passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
                passwordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            }
        }
    public static bool VerifyPasswordHash(string password, byte[] passwordHash, byte[] passwordSalt)
    {
        using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(passwordSalt))
        {
            var computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            for (int i = 0; i < computedHash.Length; i++)
            {
                if (computedHash[i] != passwordHash[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }  





public class AccessToken
    {
        public string Token { get; set; }
        public DateTime Expiration { get; set; }
    }


public interface ITokenHelper
    {
        AccessToken CreateToken(User user, List<OperationClaim> operationClaims);
    }

public JwtHelper(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _tokenOptions = Configuration.GetSection("TokenOptions").Get<TokenOptions>();

        }




    public AccessToken CreateToken(User user, List<OperationClaim> operationClaims)
    {
        _accessTokenExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_tokenOptions.AccessTokenExpiration);
        var securityKey = SecurityKeyHelper.CreateSecurityKey(_tokenOptions.SecurityKey);
        var signingCredentials = SigningCredentialsHelper.CreateSigningCredentials(securityKey);
        var jwt = CreateJwtSecurityToken(_tokenOptions, user, signingCredentials, operationClaims);
        var jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(jwt);

        return new AccessToken
        {
            Token = token,
            Expiration = _accessTokenExpiration
        };

    }




    public JwtSecurityToken CreateJwtSecurityToken(TokenOptions tokenOptions, User user,
        SigningCredentials signingCredentials, List<OperationClaim> operationClaims)
    {
        var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: tokenOptions.Issuer,
            audience: tokenOptions.Audience,
            expires: _accessTokenExpiration,
            notBefore: DateTime.Now,
            claims: SetClaims(user, operationClaims),
            signingCredentials: signingCredentials
        );
        return jwt;
    }
```

codes doing hashing and gives me this result

```
0x3BD49472981C07E354B156A9DBD11F507DFFEE40A353CD732ABED6E14035C36C31E93E8888E1E657B77B41B35E883CD5F8920DDDB3F87D1F85AFFA3E2BD1015E
```

it will doing without problem but when i tried the sign in user
i cant because when i see in local sql database i see codes are adding  zero number

```
0x3BD49472981C07E354B156A9DBD11F507DFFEE40A353CD732ABED6E14035C36C31E93E8888E1E657B77B41B35E883CD5F8920DDDB3F87D1F85AFFA3E2BD1015E00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

when  i check my codes i dont see any wrong
so what can i do this about that

Comment: Then it would be interesting how you got it into the database. Thats code you don't show. Did you choose some kind of fixed length datatype in the db?

Comment: Is perhaps the database field 128bit width rather than 64?

Comment: my data type in database binary(500) iam using like this if i change this it is going erroer so what should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if mssql, use varbinary(500) instead of binary(500)

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/sql-server/binary-and-varbinary-data-types-in-sql-server/